# How to connect two MongoDb collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to know how to add two database collections in MongoDB. Here is my code

```
async function run2(){
try {
    await client.connect();
  
    const itemCollection2 = client.db('warehouse_inventory').collection('myCollection');

    // for my items
    app.post('/items', async (req, res)=>{
        const newItem = req.body;
        const result = await itemCollection2.insertOne(newItem);
        res.send(result);
    })
   

}
finally {

}
```

}

Comment: is there an error message? the code you have shown here wont run as you need a catch statement in a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 0):

to add or create others database just take a const and change collaction name it will be create database automaticely . to use use that const name to your api cursor

```
async function run2(){
try {
   await client.connect();
   const otheritemCollection = 
   client.db('warehouse_inventory').collection('myCollection2');

    // for my other db
    app.post('/items', async (req, res)=>{
    const newItem = req.body;
    const result = await otheritemCollection.insertOne(newItem);
    res.send(result);
   })

}
finally {
```

}
}